# Change value of an element by Index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find a solution for the following problem:
There's an element which should change when another element has been changed, when it has got the same index:

```
 $("input[bez='sbd_texte']").eq(index).val() = "test";
```

The "index" variable is ok, but I can't figure out how to change the value of this specfic element.

So how can I change the value of a specfic element, which is recognized by an index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("input[bez='sbd_texte']").eq(index).val("test");
```

jQuery has a wonderful documention site, take a look on the `val` docs:

`.val( value )`  Returns: jQuery

> Description: Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Too bad you can't downvote comments ;-) Because that would just be stupid ;-)